# Select a column from maximum cell to first cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA. I got some data of 742 rows from this data I want to select from MAX value to first row. **E.g.** Suppose my maximum value is "240" in cell "A480", so I want to select a column from cell "A480" to cell "A1".

Any one know how to do this.

Comment: do you mean that max value in the column "A" should be displayed in cell "A1" ?

Comment: No... I just want to select column from "A1" to my maximum value cell i.e. in example "A480". and suppose my maximum value is in cell "A80", then select only from "A1" to "A80"

Comment: It is still not clear to me. As you said if max value is in cell "A80", then what do you want to select from "A1" to "A80"?

Comment: Sorry my dear friend... But i just want to select that range only... just normal selection.... just like we select by using "Range("A1","A80").select"...      Instead of "A80" it should be that cell which has a maximum value...

Comment: and one more addition... all my numerical data is in Column A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub MaxNumberRow()
    Dim max As Double
    Dim rowNum As Long

    With Sheet1
        max = WorksheetFunction.max(.Columns(1))

        If max > 0 Then
            rowNum = .Columns(1).Find(What:=max, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
            Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rowNum, 1)).Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Mrig... This code is not working with 6 digit numbers including 2 decimals (e.g. 2408.90, 2464.35 and so on)... I tried to find out but I am not able resolve... This code working fine with 5 digit numbers including 2 decimals... It's giving an error "Object variable or block variable not set". It is giving an error at line 10 (at rowNum variable)

Comment: Replace LookIn:=xlValues with LookIn:=xlFormulas

Comment: But then its giving error 1004 in selection at Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(rowNum,1)).Select